# why i need to define the connection string in web config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i can create the connection string in code and also in the web config file, but i am not clear why it is a best practice to define connection string into web config file.

is it only for the reason we can replace the database at any time or anything else? 
Thank you

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't have to recompile code just because you want to change database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the end result is that you can replace the database at any time, the reason is deeper than that. It is a very important practice to avoid hard-coding your program's environment, so that the deployment of your product could be done without recompiling the code.

In practice, coding and deployment are done by different groups of people, so programmers need to provide means of specifying the program's environment to the deployers. This includes, among other things,

- Connection strings to databases,
- Locations of files and directories,
- URLs of external services,
- Port numbers on which your server is listening.

Placement of connection strings in the web config file achieves this goal, but using a different configuration mechanism would also be acceptable.